# Exploit type constraints of case classes in Scala match expression

Tags: scala, types, pattern-matching

I'm building a factory that produces an instance of Product[T] for a given Config[T]. There are two types of configs:

```
trait Config[T]
case class SimpleConfig[T]() extends Config[T]
case class SpecialConfig[T <: Special]() extends Config[T]
```

The factory simply matches on the config and delegates to two sub-factories:

```
def factory[T](config: Config[T]): Product[T] = config match {
  case c: SimpleConfig[_] => buildA[T](c)
  case sc: SpecialConfig[_] => buildASpecial[T](sc)
}

def buildA[X](c: Config[X]): Product[X] = ???
def buildASpecial[X <: Special](sc: SpecialConfig[X]): Product[X] = ???
```

However, this does not compile because the compiler cannot verify that the type parameter of the config passed to `buildASpecial()` is a subtype of `Special`. It looks like it can acually verify that the parameter `sc` is a `SpecialConfig[X]` with `X <: Special` but it does not see that the `X` is in fact equal to `T` so it could conclude that `T` is also `Special`.

Maybe I'm missing something but the reasing above seems valid to me. Is it possible to fix this without an explicit cast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `Product` and `Config` are covariant, you could do the following:

```
trait Special
trait Product[+T]

trait Config[+T]
case class SimpleConfig[T]() extends Config[T]
case class SpecialConfig[T <: Special]() extends Config[T]


def buildA[X](c: Config[X]): Product[X] = ???
def buildASpecial[X <: Special](sc: SpecialConfig[X]): Product[X] = ???

def factory[T](config: Config[T]): Product[T] = config match {
  case c: SimpleConfig[T] => buildA[T](c)
  case sc: SpecialConfig[t] => buildASpecial[t](sc)
}
```

Otherwise, the subtyping issues with `T <: Special` don't seem to be easily solved by pattern matching, and must be dealt with using the good old subclass-polymorphism instead (you opted in for that by using `<:` in the first place):

```
trait Special
trait Product[T]

trait Config[T] {
  def buildProduct: Product[T]
}
case class SimpleConfig[T]() extends Config[T] {
  def buildProduct = buildA[T](this)
}
case class SpecialConfig[T <: Special]() extends Config[T] {
  def buildProduct = buildASpecial[T](this)
}


def buildA[X](c: Config[X]): Product[X] = ???
def buildASpecial[X <: Special](sc: SpecialConfig[X]): Product[X] = ???

def factory[T](config: Config[T]): Product[T] = config.buildProduct
```

Comment: It's weird that the compiler can figure out `t <: T` in the covariant case but can't figure out `t =:= T` in the simpler invariant case.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov If it unified `t` with `T`, then typechecking this simple code snippet would again require flow-sensitive analysis where `Nothing <: T <: Any` is known right on method entry, but then somehow changes to `Nothing <: T <: Special` inside the second `match-case`-branch. As far as I know, the typer does not do any flow-sensitive type analysis at all, which then results in such "weird" cases. I don't know why it doesn't do it, I assume that it's just *complex* (as in - *way* more complex that this simple example suggests). I'd love to see better workarounds.

Comment: That would be required to allow `case sc: SpecialConfig[t] => buildASpecial[T](sc)` to compile, but I don't think `case sc: SpecialConfig[t] => buildASpecial[t](sc)` necessarily needs it: `t <: Special` and `t ~ T` can be used separately.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately `Product` is invariant in `T` so I have to resort to the second approach. However, it seems very reasonable in my case anyway.